# Symbol "&" when dragging directory in terminal VSC

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

When I'm trying to drag a directory in my VS Code integrated terminal (PowerShell), it keeps adding "&" symbol between "cd" and directory. example `>> cd & 'c:\users...`

I don't know what to do. My solution is to scroll through and delete it...

```
Version: 1.83.1 (user setup)
Commit: f1b07bd25dfad64b0167beb15359ae573aecd2cc
Date: 2023-10-10T23:48:05.904Z
Electron: 25.8.4
ElectronBuildId: 24154031
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22621
```

Comment: I guess dragging a directory doesn't do what you're expecting it to do.

Comment: I just want to paste the actual directory to target that specific folder

Comment: Right-click the directory instead, pick "copy path" and then `cd <paste>` in your terminal.

Comment: It make sense but then i need to put apostrophe manually ( ' )

Comment: @Barmar no `&` is added for me when using a Bash terminal profile. Something more interesting is going on here. Guleta, I'll try to do some investigation, but no promises that I'll find anything.